# How can I install Slack app on an old Galaxy S6 phone?

Tags: applications, installation

I am near certain that Slack works (or worked) on Galaxy S6 phones back in the day, but now when I try to install it, it's not available as supported in the Google Play store.  Is there any way I can still get the app image and install it onto my S6 phone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The recent version of Slack v22.01.11.0 for Android I can see on [apkpure.com](https://apkpure.com/de/slack/com.Slack) defines in it's AndroidManifest.xml `android:minSdkVersion="26"` so this app requires at least Android 8.0.

The Galaxy S6 comes (according to [gsmarena.com](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-6849.php)) with Android 5.0.2 (Lollipop), upgradable to Android 8.0 (Oreo). So if your device is fully upgraded to Android 8 you should be able to install Slack from [Google PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack) or from a web site that provides the APK like https://apkpure.com https://apkmirror.com ...

Comment: Thank you so much for this info, @Robert.  I'm understanding now why it isn't showing up for me in the Google PlayStore -- I have Android 7.0.  Not 8.  So I guess I need to figure out why that's not on there and how to (manually) upgrade that first.  Then hopefully the Slack app will install.